# Sum of 3 angles

Tags: trigonometry

If $\alpha+\beta-\gamma=\pi$, show that 
$$\sin^2\alpha+\sin^2\beta-\sin^2\gamma=2\sin\alpha\sin\beta\cos\gamma$$
Please don't ask about ideas because I really don't have one. I was initially thinking about a triangle with the given angles... But no chance
EDIT. Sorry guys, now is correct.

Comment: This seems incorrect - take $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=\frac{\pi}3$. The RHS is irrational but the LHS is not

Comment: Are you sure of it? Shouldn't it be $$\sin(\alpha)^2+\sin(\beta)^2+\sin(\gamma)^2$$?

Comment: You needed $\cos\gamma$ on the RHS.

Comment: Looks from the duplicate as though you need $\cos \gamma$ in the product